# Open Google Chrome search-in-page function with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is it somehow possible to open this search with JavaScript ?

If yes, can we also pass it some default value ?

[image]

#### Context

I want to create a search function that highlight every element in my page that match the searched functionality like this

[image]

Comment: I don't think so no, since the search is part of the browser and not the DOM.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm afraid you're right, maybe someone have something on this internet, maybe with google API stuff... But cannot find anything

Answer (score 0):

Try using window.find(*stringtofind*)

Src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find

Comment: This doesn't work? Even the demo on mdn doesn't work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer, but as @evolutionxbox say, this doesn't work and will be dropped in the future.. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=672395